# Dual citizen layover in US

Tags: us-citizens

I’ve had to change my travel plans last minute and the only return flight available is via the US with my final destination in the UK. I’m a dual US/UK citizen, but I’m not currently carrying my US passport because I didn’t think I’d need it on this trip.

As a US citizen it sounds like I can’t apply for an ESTA on my UK passport. Is there any other way I can get this flight or do I have to find a different route home?

Comment: There's nothing legally preventing you from getting an ESTA. You will have to declare your US citizenship, but (IIRC) some people have had success getting an ESTA despite that. It is worth a try if you can afford the few dollars

Comment: This is why I always carry both of my passports with me when I travel.  You never know what might come up.

Answer (score 3):

Tricky. As a US citizen you are required to use your US passport to enter the US but there is no penalty for not doing so and you can't be denied entry. However you need to somehow proof to the immigration agent that you do have a US passport and they can drag the whole process out as long as they feel like which clearly includes you missing your connection.

If you can get a photocopy of you passport and birth certificate or naturalization certificate and what ever other proof of US citizenship you can muster you may get lucky: approach the immigration officer with the full story: why you don't have your passport on you, that you only be in the country for a few hours, that you have proof of imminent departure and that you try to collect as many documents supporting your story as was feasible.

A "reasonable" immigration officer will let this go, but there is, unfortunately,  no guarantee for that. A grumpy one may look at your boarding pass for the connecting flight, and keep you there just long enough to miss your connection.

I would also contact the airline, explain your situation, ask for advice and specifically ask what would happen of you miss your connection because of immigration delays.

Comment: If you don't have documents listed in Timatic as allowing you to enter the US (you wouldn't without an ESTA or a US passport) you may not be allowed to board the flight at all. You will probably want to talk to the airline about getting boarded as well.

Comment: @ArtemisTosini if the ESTA is refused, there is no way the airline will board the passenger unless the passenger goes to a US consulate and gets an emergency passport.  I believe this will result in the cancellation of the existing passport, but it might not.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the best solution, but if the US does not approve the ESTA application with your UK passport then the only option other than changing your flight will be to go to a US consulate and apply for a new passport.  They can issue an emergency passport very quickly, though I believe this will result in the cancellation of your existing passport. The US does issue second passports to travelers with a demonstrated need for one, but I believe it requires submitting your existing passport with the application, and I suspect that consular officers generally won't consider failing to anticipate a change in plans to be a genuine need.  Still, it can't hurt to ask.